OAuth2Client Error: The incoming JSON object does not contain a client_email field
I am using Google's OAuth2Client for my first time and running to some issues. I can login to OAuth2 just fine and generate a set of credentials I save in localStorage for future use. I am building the application in next.js using libraries...
{ google } from 'googleapis';
const { OAuth2Client } = require('google-auth-library');

However, later when I attempt to load these saved credentials into google.auth.fromJSON(), I get the error message "Error: The incoming JSON object does not contain a client_email field" despite said field being defined in the json object.
'savedCredentials' => {
   "type":"authorized_user",
   "client_id":"774blabblahblabblah.apps.googleusercontent.com",
   "client_secret":"GOfoobarfoobar",
   "client_email":"myemailaddress.com",
   "refresh_token":"1//helloworldhelloworldhellow"
}

Any insight or directions to troubleshoot would be apperciated.

I do know why my json credentials were good enough for the fromJSON() method, but a workaround is passing in the tokens as an Object to setCredentials().
let client = new OAuth2Client(
    client_id,
    client_secret,
    redirect_uris[1],
);
const tokens = client.getToken(code)
savedCredentials.tokens = tokens;

...

const client = new OAuth2Client;
client.setCredentials(savedCredentials.tokens);

